# Save the result of LINQ query to list

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to create handler to save the result of LINQ query to list and that what i reached to

```
public static List<string> Get()
{
    LesamisContainer LC = new LesamisContainer();

    List<string> list = (from pb in LC.PayBills
                         join c in LC.Customers on pb.CustomerId equals c.Id
                         join d in LC.Departments on pb.DepartmentId equals d.Id
                         select new { pb.Id, c.FullName, d.Name, pb.Discount, pb.TotalAmount, pb.Details, pb.Date, pb.CustomerId, pb.DepartmentId } into x
                         select x).Tolist();
    return list;
}
```

but i got this exception

http://i60.tinypic.com/2lxu2o.png

> Cannnot convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'

Comment: Your query returns anonymous type with multiple properties, but you're trying to save it to a `List<string>`. How would you expect that to work?

Comment: i'm beginner at programing and that's why i asking for help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're creating an anonymous type with

```
select new { pb.Id, c.FullName, d.Name, pb.Discount, pb.TotalAmount, pb.Details, pb.Date, pb.CustomerId, pb.DepartmentId } into x
```

The `select x` just returns this type. To get a `List<string>` you would need to return on of the properties from this instead, eg: `select x.FullName`

That would be a pretty odd way of doing things though, and probably not what you really intend. I assume you don't actually want a `List<string>`.

In which case, since you're returning the result from the method it should be declared and not anonymous:

```
public class PayBillModel 
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    ...
}
```

then

```
select new PayBillModel() { pb.Id, c.FullName, d.Name, pb.Discount, pb.TotalAmount, pb.Details, pb.Date, pb.CustomerId, pb.DepartmentId }
```

This way, you end up with a `List<PayBillModel>`.

Comment: i actually want a List to bind data to datagridview, and without initialize class for it, cuz i working with entity framework modal first and this will cuz quite lot of problems with generate database query in future
it work for me but it not the result i want

Answer (score 1):

You're getting multiple types. Try changing the `List` type to `object` instead of `string`

```
List<object> list = (from pb in LC.PayBills
                         join c in LC.Customers on pb.CustomerId equals c.Id
                         join d in LC.Departments on pb.DepartmentId equals d.Id
                         select new { pb.Id, c.FullName, d.Name, pb.Discount, pb.TotalAmount, pb.Details, pb.Date, pb.CustomerId, pb.DepartmentId } into x
                         select x).Tolist();
```

You can then browse through the list by:

```
foreach (object item in list)
{
   if (item is pb.Id)
   { 
      //do something
   }

   //or
   //if (item.GetType() == typeof(PayBills)) { }
}
```